# Git Push - Heroku & BitBucket

Tags: git

I push changes and it says it commits them. And I use heroku run python and it still is using the old code.

How do I get it to commit to Heroku?

I have checked `git remote -v` and it says - which is correct - there are two remotes - one to BitBucket and one to Heroku - but why doesn't Heroku update the changes.

The only way I can update changes is to use `git push heroku master` which takes a lot of time. Is there a faster approach

Answer (score 3):

Create a third remote that contains both locations.

```
git remote add all ssh://git@bitbucket.org/bitbucketusername/bitbucketreponame.git
git remote set-url --add all git@heroku.com:yourherokuappname.git
git push all master
```